# How can I open mp4 or other video files by native way on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, mp4

I am developing a function that when clicking an mp4 video, I should open it in a native way, just like clicking mp4 file on file browser. I do know that there are a lot of dependencies that allow me play videos inside react native, I just consider that playing video in native way provides more options for users and lesser bugs whenever save or share it. So, do you guys have any ideas that allow open the video file in a native way? Very thanks!

Comment: Can you please add some code snippets to get what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @DhevendhiranM I just want to open my mp4 file by a native player, not playing it inside my react-native app, I am using react-native-viewer, it's working now

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement react-native-video for online streaming and if you have downloaded file then you can just use Linking by react-native

Comment: You are right, I can open it by using Link maybe. Anyway, I am using react-native-viewer, it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way that by using react-native-viewer can open the mp4 file natively